# Haskell type error: Type : a Int, Does not match : Int

Tags: haskell, typeerror

I need to generate a random number from 1 to 5 which isn't already in the passed list.

Here is my code:

```
questionNumberGenerator:: [Int]->Int
questionNumberGenerator ql = do
    g <- newStdGen
    let qn=(fst((randomR (1, 5) g)))::Int
    let element = (elem qn ql)::Bool
    if(element==True)
        then
           questionNumberGenerator ql
        else do
           return qn
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is your type signature; it should be:

```
questionNumberGenerator :: [Int] -> IO Int
```

`questionNumberGenerator` returns an IO action (which it must, to use the global random number generator), but your type signature says it's pure.

If you want to use `questionNumberGenerator` in pure code, you'll have to thread the random number generator state explicitly, like this:

```
questionNumberGenerator :: (RandomGen g) => [Int] -> g -> (Int, g)
questionNumberGenerator ql g =
    let (qn, g') = randomR (1, 5) g
        element = elem qn ql
    in if (element==True)
           then questionNumberGenerator ql g'
           else (qn, g')
```

By the way, `(element==True)` is redundant; `element` means the exact same thing.